# How to make exim4 deny other ips from sending mail using the server?

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim

How to make exim4 so that it only allow smtp connection to send mail from 127.0.0.1 only. but also recieve mail at the same time. I am confused with this because if I change `dc_local_interfaces` to `127.0.0.1`, it is unable to receive mail, but only allows 127.0.0.1, which is what I want. But, I also want to receive mail from the internet while it allows only 127.0.0.1 to send mail.

I am using Ubuntu. But I think this is probably not really related to Ubuntu.

update-exim4.conf.conf

```
# /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
#
# Edit this file and /etc/mailname by hand and execute update-exim4.conf
# yourself or use 'dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config'
#
# Please note that this is _not_ a dpkg-conffile and that automatic changes
# to this file might happen. The code handling this will honor your local
# changes, so this is usually fine, but will break local schemes that mess
# around with multiple versions of the file.
#
# update-exim4.conf uses this file to determine variable values to generate
# exim configuration macros for the configuration file.
#
# Most settings found in here do have corresponding questions in the
# Debconf configuration, but not all of them.
#
# This is a Debian specific file

dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='mydomain.com'
dc_local_interfaces='0.0.0.0 ; ::0'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

I can't post exim4.conf.template cuz of stackexchange character limitation sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Maybe you could just add authentication, because i don't see any particular method of doing this. i've done the resarch.

Comment: Any reasonable default configuration should already do this. You should provide your actual configuration here if you still want assistance.

Comment: I can't post the config here. Because of limit of 30k characters. I can say that I have not modified the exim4.conf.template from the install. only update-exim4.conf is modified.

Comment: You've got an answer. check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed to postfix because of this.

Answer (score 0):

In the default exim4 configuration, the `relay_from_hosts` list determines which hosts can send mail from your server. See the Exim docs:

- [Chapter 7 - The default configuration file](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html) shows typical usage.
- [Chapter 44 - Access control lists](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html), section 52 - Using an ACL to control relaying, shows details of how `relay_from_hosts` is used to control relaying with access control lists.

Comment: I changed my `relay_from_hosts` to `127.0.0.1`, and `local_domains` to `@`, and the mail server stop recieving mails even if i open it to 0.0.0.0 and ::0. It works until I do that. And it only works again if I reinstall exim4. I checked the log, and it says `rejected RCPT myself@mydomain.com`

Comment: If I change `local_domains` to my domain name instead, it works, but still allows remote relay.